# How can I make a JavaScript class instance be instance of another class?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, instance, winston

I'm attempting to use [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) for logging in my project. To create a new logger, you would typically do:

```
import winston from 'winston';
const logger = winston.createLogger({ ...opts });
```

However, my options will be largely the same across the project, save for a `label` option, which will be the name of the module doing the logging. Rather than duplicate the `createLogger` code across 100 files, I'd like to create a wrapper class that provides the most common options to `createLogger`, and allows the user to provide one param for `label` to the constructor. The instance of the class should be an instance of winston's `Logger` class, which is the return value of `createLogger`.

So to summarize, I'd like to be able to do this:

```
import OurLogger from './our-logger';
const fooModuleLogger = new OurLogger('foo'); // full winston Logger instance
```

My best shot right now at `OurLogger.js` would look something like:

```
import winston from 'winston';
export default class {
    constructor(label = 'defaultLabel') {
        const defaultOpts = { ... }

        // I know this part is wrong. But what's the right way?
        this = winston.createLogger({
            label,
            ...defaultOpts
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this as a class? Seems like a perfect example of just exporting a function.

Comment: Yes, I don't get the class usage. Just have something like `getLogger = label => winston.createLogger({ ...opts, label });`

Comment: Also, for the record, even in Java where it's full of classes, you'd usually have a factory that returns you the loggers. I wouldn't expect and haven't even seen anybody write their own custom Logger class to wrap around the logger factory.

Comment: Right, I should have mentioned that I'm aware of the option to simply export a function. And maybe that's the best route to take here. This particular question has been a curiosity of mine for a while, so I thought this would be a good opportunity to ask and attempt to implement.

Comment: @MegaMatt as I hinted in the first line of my answer, the only real way to do this is to wrap every method/property in a class of your own and pass that on to the underlying instance. It has its uses, but probably not what you wanted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign `this` and without making wrapper methods for every bit of functionality a class doesn't feel like the right thing here.

Why not just export a function and use that?

```
export default function OurLogger(label){
    const defaultOpts = { ... }
    return winston.createLogger({
        label,
        ...defaultOpts
    });
}
```

And then just

```
import OurLogger from './our-logger';
const fooModuleLogger = OurLogger('foo'); // full winston Logger instance
```

Comment: I'd swap the positions of `...defaultOpts` and `label`, so the latter can override the former. You can then include a default label in the `defaultOpts` object.